# How to filter my average function depending on user selection?

Tags: javascript, user-controls

I am trying to filter my average function depending on users selection
I'm using JavaScript and all my data are in a JSON file

My average function is:

```
function loadJSONishDataOften() { //function for the average often button 
var m = JSON.parse(data);
var myObjectArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    myObjectArray[i] = new MediaClass (m[i].favorite, m[i].day, m[i].often, m[i].lon, m[i].device, m[i].advert );
}   
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "On average people go on social media: " + " " + calulateAverageOften(myObjectArray) + " times per day."; }

function calulateAverageOften() {  
var jsonObjects = JSON.parse(data);
var suml=0;
for(var i=0; i<jsonObjects.length;i++){
  suml += Number(jsonObjects[i].often);  
 }
 return  suml/jsonObjects.length;
 }
```

Then to filter my data I created a switch function:

```
function myFunction(value) { /
var userChoice = " ";  
userChoice = document.getElementById("choose").value; 
switch (userChoice) { //switch to do something depending of the user choice
                case "Everything": { 
                createReport(myArray);
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "In this Research we had " + myArray.length + " participants." 
                break;
            } 
                case "facebook": {  //case of facebook
                var FB =[];
                FB = getObjects(myArray, "favorite", "facebook");  //has to find all the facebook in favorite in json file
                getObjects(myArray, "favorite", "facebook"); 
                createReport(FB);
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =  FB.length +" participants chose Facebook as their favorite Social Media"; 
        break;
            }
```

And it goes on for each case

Now on my HTML page, users can choose a social app and it will display the data of this app, and my average function show the average for every app I would like to be able that when a user choose one app, it will display the average only for that app

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To filter arrays you just use .filter() function

```
var facebookEntries = JSON.parse(jsondata).filter(function (entry) {
    return entry.favorite === 'facebook';
});
var facebookEntries = array.filter(function (entry) {
    return entry.favorite === 'facebook';
});
```

In your example

```
 switch (userChoice) { //switch to do something depending of the user choice
    case "Everything": { 
        createReport(myArray);
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "In this Research we had " + myArray.length + " participants." ;
        break;
    } 
    case "facebook": {  //case of facebook
       var FB = array.filter(function (entry) {return entry.favorite === 'facebook';});
       createReport(FB);
       document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =  FB.length +" participants chose Facebook as their favorite Social Media"; 
       break;
    }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter